# ntheorem subhypotheses

Tags: ntheorem

I'm trying to create:

```
 Hypothesis 1a
 Hypothesis 1b
 Hypothesis 2a
 Hypothesis 2b
 Hypothesis 3
```

I followed the code from [an earlier thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147882/5001), but instead of getting "Hypothesis 3", I get "Hypothesis 2c".

What should I do to get "Hypothesis 3"? Thanks so much for all your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremindent1\parindent
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Hypothesis}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{pretheorem}
\counterwithin{theorem}{pretheorem}
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\arabic{pretheorem}\alph{theorem}}
\newcommand{\theoremgroup}{\refstepcounter{pretheorem}}
\begin{document}
\theoremgroup
    \begin{theorem}
        This is Hypothesis 1a
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        This is Hypothesis 1b
    \end{theorem}
\theoremgroup
    \begin{theorem}
        This is Hypothesis 2a
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        This is Hypothesis 2b
    \end{theorem}
\theoremgroup
    \begin{theorem}
        This is Hypothesis 3, but I'm getting Hypothesis 2c
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I get 3a and not 2c.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the code for `subequations` from `amsmath`. Since this is independent from `ntheorem`, I omit that part from the example; you can add the setting for the theorem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{parenthypothesis}
\newenvironment{subhypothesis}
 {
  \refstepcounter{hypothesis}%
  \protected@edef\theparenthypothesis{\thehypothesis}%
  \setcounter{parenthypothesis}{\value{hypothesis}}%
  \setcounter{hypothesis}{0}%
  \def\thehypothesis{\theparenthypothesis\alph{hypothesis}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{hypothesis}{\value{parenthypothesis}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subhypothesis}
\begin{hypothesis}
This is Hypothesis 1a
\end{hypothesis}

\begin{hypothesis}
This is Hypothesis 1b
\end{hypothesis}
\end{subhypothesis}

\begin{subhypothesis}
\begin{hypothesis}
This is Hypothesis 2a
\end{hypothesis}
\begin{hypothesis}
This is Hypothesis 2b
\end{hypothesis}
\end{subhypothesis}

\begin{hypothesis}
This is Hypothesis 3
\end{hypothesis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided generates the number "3a" for the final hypothesis. If you want it to be numbered "3", i.e., without any suffix, you need to replace the final `\theoremgroup` directive with

```
\counterwithout{theorem}{pretheorem}
```